# Unexpected Pandas/Arrow behaviour using series.apply

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using `pandas` and the `arrow` datetime extension package to manipulate some dates. My code is the following:

```
srs = pd.Series(['2016-10-02T00:24:15.707Z','2016-10-02T00:24:27.294Z','2016-10-02T01:15:56.682Z'])
dt = srs.apply(arrow.get,tz="Europe/Paris")
ym = dt.apply(arrow.arrow.Arrow.format,'MMM-YY')
print(ym)
```

which prints:

```
0    2016-10-02 00:24:15+00:00
1    2016-10-02 00:24:27+00:00
2    2016-10-02 01:15:56+00:00
dtype: object
```

And

```
yearmonths=[]

for ind,row in dt.iteritems():
    yearmonth = row.format('MMM-YY')
    yearmonths.append(yearmonth)
print(yearmonths)
```

which prints:

```
['Oct-16', 'Oct-16', 'Oct-16']
```

I do not understand why the uppermost code block does not produce the same output as the lower block as it seems to me that it should. Have I missed something or is this a bug?

Comment: I think it would be much more efficient to use internal Pandas methods - using `arrow` will be very slow and i don't think it's a good idea to store objects of `arrow` dtype in Pandas cells - you won't be able to use vectorized (fast) methods. Your task can be easily done using internal pandas/numpy methods. Why do you need `arrow`?

Comment: You have your answers below. They all work elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apply` function applies the values in the series as the argument into your `format` function. Therefore it's not returning what you want. Basically, think of apply as doing the following (in pseudocode):

```
for value in the_series:
    format(value, 'MMM-YY')
```

But the signature of `format` is `format(your_date_format)`

If you want to use `apply` and get the same result as the bottom, you would have to create a custom function:

```
def format_date(date):
    return date.format('MMM-YY')

ym = dt.apply(format_date)
```

Result:

```
0    Oct-16
1    Oct-16
2    Oct-16
```

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve the same goal using internal Pandas methods:

```
In [54]: pd.to_datetime(srs).dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris').dt.strftime('%b-%y')
Out[54]:
0    Oct-16
1    Oct-16
2    Oct-16
```

Comment: This was a very helpful answer and I would be happy to ask another question along the lines of 'how to achieve this in pandas directly?' and accept this as the answer...

Comment: @seanysull, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you run

`ym = dt.apply(lambda x: x.format('MMM-YY'))`

instead? That is more equivalent to what you do in the `iteritems` example.

Comment: Please explain. Explaining how the function works, will add value over the file of the answer.